# Receiving mail for an account that isn't mine

Tags: gmail

My Gmail account is formatted as `Firstname.LastName@gmail.com`. However I have been receiving emails addressed to: `FirstNameLastName@gmail.com`.

It's been going for a little while, but now over the last couple of months it has become worse. I was letting the senders know. I'm afraid some of my email may be going to this other person's mailbox!

What can I do?

Comment: Hi John, and welcome to Web Applications! If you're satisfied with @Ashton's answer below, please click the _Accept_ button next to it. Then your question will be marked as "answered", and Ashton and you will receive some reputation points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the owner of the account `FirstNameLastName@gmail.com`, you will get all emails sent to `FirstName.LastName@gmail.com`.

Gmail does not recognize the dots as characters. So if an email gets sent to `F.i.r.s.t.Name.L.a.s.t.Name@gmail.com`, the account `FirstNameLastName@gmail.com` will still get the email.

> Insert one or several dots (".") anywhere in your email address. Gmail doesn't recognize periods as characters in addresses -- we just ignore them. For example, you could tell people your address was hikingfan@gmail.com, hiking.fan@gmail.com or hi.kin.g.fan@gmail.com.

Source: [2 hidden ways to get more from your Gmail address](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html)